# What I do in javascript to get my required result?

Tags: javascript, required

Here is my javascript code

```
for (var i = 1; i <= _MAXPAGECOUNT - 2; i++) {

        e = document.getElementsByName("q" + i + "[]");
        for (var j = 0; j <= e.length - 1; j++) {
            if (e[j].checked) {
                result = result + "," + i + ":" +  e[j].value;

               // break;
            }
        }}
```

The problem is this, it shows result like this **1:2,1:3,1:4,2:3,2:4,2:5**
here in code `i` means question number and `j` means answer number, but I want to result as like this **1:2,3,4 ; 2:3,4,5**

Comment: Ugh, why do you use `<= x - 1` instead of just ` < x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for (var i = 1; i <= _MAXPAGECOUNT - 2; i++) {
        result = result+i+":";
        e = document.getElementsByName("q" + i + "[]");
        for (var j = 0; j <= e.length - 1; j++) {
            if (e[j].checked) {
                result = result + e[j].value;
               // break;
            }
        }
        if(i<_MAXPAGECOUNT - 2)
        {
             result = result+" ; ";
        }
}
```